# Bi-directional text in an HTML select

Tags: javascript, html, css, internationalization, bidi

I'm trying to design a select box where the elements may be in multiple languages.  I would like all the text aligned the same way (right or left, or heck even centered) and the text-direction to be correct.  I can do this programmatically from the back end, but its a pain so I'm looking for a HTML/CSS/(JS) solution if possible.

This solution makes the text aligned uniformly, but the direction for ltr text is wrong (assuming `Arabic (Saudi)` is translated)

```
<select dir="ltr">
  <option value="/es_PE/">español (Perú)</option>
  <option value="/ar_SA/">Arabic (Saudi)</option>
</select>
```

Output:

```
español (Perú)
Saudi) Arabic)
```

This solution ensures that the text-direction is correct, but the text-alignment is not uniform.

```
<select>
  <option value="/es_PE/" dir="auto">español (Perú)</option>
  <option value="/ar_SA/" dir="auto">Arabic (Saudi)</option>
</select>
```

Output:

```
español (Perú)
        (Saudi) Arabic
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1v9hs8v/1/

Is there some way to make sure that text-direction is correct for the entire string and also give each option a uniform text-alignment?  The `text-alignment` css style seems to have no effect on select objects.

EDIT:  this is possibly a problem with Chrome only.  FF and IE appear to render the second solution correctly.

Comment: This may help you: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It looks like option is as tightly as I can wrap the text direction within a select, the browser removes tags within an option tag.